# PHP arrays to table with no luck

Tags: php, arrays

```
    Array (    

    [x0] => sometext1     
    [x1] => sometext2     
    [x2] => sometext3    
    [x3] => sometext4     
    [x4] => sometext5    
    [x5] => sometext6
    [x?] => sometext?

    [y0] => someothertext1     
    [y1] => someothertext2  
    [y2] => someothertext3     
    [y3] => someothertext4     
    [y4] => someothertext5     
    [y5] => someothertext6
    [y?] => someothertext?

    )
```

I am trying to take this array and create a table. Basically I don't know how many x or y will be... I couldn't find any solution so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The Result I am trying to get

Table

```
   x      |       y
sometext1 | someothertext1
sometext2 | someothertext2
...       | ...
```

Comment: what is the table that you want?

Comment: what are these x and y rows and coloms ?

Comment: x and y will be columns.

I couldnt figure it out how to get those values to the table rows.

Comment: what is your table structure? how many rows and columns?

Comment: and the value will be correspoding value for the columns rite ?

Comment: What is the output yo needed..??

Comment: x and y are repeating with those numbers.

Prasanth you are right. Those will be corresponding value for the columns

Comment: Sherin, Thats my output. I am receiving from db. I want to transfer it to human readable table

Answer (score 1):

If possible, do a small correction to the array, on how it is declared. Make it look this way:

```
Array (    
    [x] => Array (
        [0] => sometext1     
        [1] => sometext2     
        [2] => sometext3    
        [3] => sometext4     
        [4] => sometext5    
        [5] => sometext6
        [?] => sometext?
    )
    [y] => Array (
        [0] => sometext1     
        [1] => sometext2     
        [2] => sometext3    
        [3] => sometext4     
        [4] => sometext5    
        [5] => sometext6
        [?] => sometext?
    )
)
```

And in this way, using PHP, you can do the table this way:

```
<table>
<?php
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($array as $heading => $contents)
        echo "<th>$heading</th>";
    echo '</tr>';
    foreach ($array as $heading => $contents)
        foreach ($heading as $value)
            echo "<td>$value</td>";
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @Praveen, But I actually I dont know how I can convert it to your edition. Can you help to figure it out?

Comment: @user1605661 : check my answer for this format

Comment: @user1605661 Okay, then Prasanth's answer will suit you. Mine will be better for maintainability.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
    <?php
$array  = Array('x0' => 'sometext1',     
                'x1' => 'sometext2',     
                'x2' => 'sometext3',    
                'x3' => 'sometext4',     
                'x4' => 'sometext5',    
                'x5' => 'sometext',
                'y0' => 'someothertext1',     
                'y1' => 'someothertext2',  
                'y2' => 'someothertext3',     
                'y3' => 'someothertext4',     
                'y4' => 'someothertext5',     
                'y5' => 'someothertext6',
                );

$res    = array();              
foreach($array as $key=>$val){
    preg_match('/(?P<var>\w{1})(?P<ky>\d+)/',$key, $match);
    $res[$match['ky']][$match['var']] = $val;
}


echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><td>X</td><td>Y</td></tr>";
foreach($res as $keys=>$vals){  
    echo "<tr><td>".$vals['x']."</td><td>".$vals['y']."</td></tr>";
}
echo "<table>";

?>
```

Output :

```
X           Y
sometext1   someothertext1
sometext2   someothertext2
sometext3   someothertext3
sometext4   someothertext4
sometext5   someothertext5
sometext    someothertext6
```

Comment: try with this array `$array  = Array('x0' => 'sometext1',     
                'x1' => 'sometext2',     
                'x2' => 'sometext3',    
                'x3' => 'sometext4',     
                'x4' => 'sometext5',    
                'x11' => 'sometext',
                'y0' => 'someothertext1',     
                'y1' => 'someothertext2',  
                'y2' => 'someothertext3',     
                'y3' => 'someothertext4',     
                'y4' => 'someothertext5',     
                'y11' => 'someothertext6',
                );`

Comment: Edited the answer, I guess this is the one you need

Comment: @SherinJose : it works fine with your array

Comment: @SherinJose :  change ???

Comment: last one more question, If after x and y, there is z but its not looping to 1.2.3.4.5. only z. Is this still be working? Just a question. Other that that I really appreciate. Thanks

Comment: try using an index greaterthan 9

Comment: i used `\d+` it works fine with your array, Have you tried it ?

Comment: @PrasanthBendra, I am working on it now. I will let you know the output in 2mins. Thanks

Comment: i got error for this array `$array  = Array('x10' => 'sometext123',     
                'x11' => 'sometext22',     
                'x12' => 'sometext322',    
                'x13' => 'sometext411',     
                'x14' => 'sometext511',    
                'x15' => 'sometext655',
                'y10' => 'someothertext1',     
                'y11' => 'someothertext2',  
                'y12' => 'someothertext3',     
                'y13' => 'someothertext4',     
                'y14' => 'someothertext5',     
                'y15' => 'someothertext6',
                );` check it

Comment: @PrasanthBendra, I am speechless. Thank you so much. Its working.

I will search this part. '/(?P<var>\w+)(?P<ky>\d+)/'. just my knowledge for future. Thanks again

Comment: @user1605661 : In stack over flow we say thanks by accepting the answer and up voting it :P

Comment: @SherinJose : yes you are right, I made a slight change `\w+` to `\w{1}` , it works fine now...Thank you :)

Comment: now the array is formatted....but you may need to change the foreach also...:)

Comment: @SherinJose :  why ??? it works proper now

Comment: the formatted array will looks like `Array([x] => Array([10] =>sometext123 [11] => sometext22 [12] => sometext322   [13] => sometext411  [14] => sometext511
            [15] => sometext655
            [25] => sometext655
        )

    [y] => Array
        (
            [10] => someothertext1
            [11] => someothertext2
            [12] => someothertext3
            [13] => someothertext4
            [14] => someothertext5
            [15] => someothertext6
            [25] => someothertext6
        )

)` then how can you fetch `$vals['x']` and ``$vals['y']``

Comment: @SherinJose : NO, it wil be like this : Array
(
    [10] => Array
        (
            [x] => sometext123
            [y] => someothertext1
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [x] => sometext22
            [y] => someothertext2
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [x] => sometext322
            [y] => someothertext3
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [x] => sometext411
            [y] => someothertext4
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [x] => sometext511
            [y] => someothertext5
        )

)

Comment: k now you are right bhai...previously you are used `$res[$match['var']][$match['ky']] = $val;`..thats y i didn't get the output...

Answer (score 0):

Copy that array into another var for this example you have two arrays with the names $arr and $arr2 that is just a copy of each.

```
$arr = $arr2 = Array (    .... );

foreach($arr as $key=>$data)
{
    $num = substr($key,1);
    echo '<tr><td>'.$data.'</td>';
    foreach($arr2 as $key2=>$data2)
    {
        $num2 = substr($key2,1);
        if($num == $num2)
        {
            echo '<td>'.$data.'</td>';
            break;
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

This of course doesn't take into account things like fixing a missing td if there is no "y" to match an "x" extra.

Answer (score 0):

As Praveen Kumar explained the table looks like this:

```
#   X              y
0   sometext1     sometext1
1   sometext2     sometext2
```